# Add "a" tag to Highcharts Org Chart

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I am going to make some changes in Highcharts Org Chart. I want to add an "a" tag to only one of the nodes of Highcharts Organization Chart ][enter link description here][1]
For example I want to change'board' node to an 'a' tag so the user can be able to click on it. can you please help me How can I do that?
Thank you so much

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        height: 600,
        inverted: true
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Highcharts Org Chart'
    },

    accessibility: {
        point: {
            descriptionFormatter: function (point) {
                var nodeName = point.toNode.name,
                    nodeId = point.toNode.id,
                    nodeDesc = nodeName === nodeId ? nodeName : nodeName + ', ' + nodeId,
                    parentDesc = point.fromNode.id;
                return point.index + '. ' + nodeDesc + ', reports to ' + parentDesc + '.';
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        type: 'organization',
        name: 'Highsoft',
        keys: ['from', 'to'],
        data: [
            ['Shareholders', 'Board'],
            ['Board', 'CEO'],
            ['CEO', 'CTO'],
            ['CEO', 'CPO'],
            ['CEO', 'CSO'],
            ['CEO', 'HR'],
            ['CTO', 'Product'],
            ['CTO', 'Web'],
            ['CSO', 'Sales'],
            ['HR', 'Market'],
            ['CSO', 'Market'],
            ['HR', 'Market'],
            ['CTO', 'Market']
        ],
        levels: [{
            level: 0,
            color: 'silver',
            dataLabels: {
                color: 'black'
            },
            height: 25
        }, {
            level: 1,
            color: 'silver',
            dataLabels: {
                color: 'black'
            },
            height: 25
        }, {
            level: 2,
            color: '#980104'
        }, {
            level: 4,
            color: '#359154'
        }],
        nodes: [{
            id: 'Shareholders'
        }, {
            id: 'Board'
        }, {
            id: 'CEO',
            title: 'CEO',
            name: 'Atle Sivertsen',
            image: 'https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/30081411/portrett-sorthvitt.jpg'
        }, {
            id: 'HR',
            title: 'CFO',
            name: 'Anne Jorunn Fjærestad',
            color: '#007ad0',
            image: 'https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/17131210/Highsoft_04045_.jpg'
        }, {
            id: 'CTO',
            title: 'CTO',
            name: 'Christer Vasseng',
            image: 'https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/17131120/Highsoft_04074_.jpg'
        }, {
            id: 'CPO',
            title: 'CPO',
            name: 'Torstein Hønsi',
            image: 'https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/17131213/Highsoft_03998_.jpg'
        }, {
            id: 'CSO',
            title: 'CSO',
            name: 'Anita Nesse',
            image: 'https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/17131156/Highsoft_03834_.jpg'
        }, {
            id: 'Product',
            name: 'Product developers'
        }, {
            id: 'Web',
            name: 'Web devs, sys admin'
        }, {
            id: 'Sales',
            name: 'Sales team'
        }, {
            id: 'Market',
            name: 'Marketing team',
            column: 5
        }],
        colorByPoint: false,
        color: '#007ad0',
        dataLabels: {
            color: 'white'
        },
        borderColor: 'white',
        nodeWidth: 65
    }],
    tooltip: {
        outside: false
    },
    exporting: {
        allowHTML: true,
        sourceWidth: 800,
        sourceHeight: 600
    }

});
```

```css
.highcharts-figure,
.highcharts-data-table table {
    min-width: 360px;
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}

.highcharts-data-table table {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    margin: 10px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
}

.highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 1em 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #555;
}

.highcharts-data-table th {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table td,
.highcharts-data-table th,
.highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 0.5em;
}

.highcharts-data-table thead tr,
.highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f8f8f8;
}

.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
    background: #f1f7ff;
}

#container h4 {
    text-transform: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

#container p {
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    #container h4 {
        font-size: 2.3vw;
        line-height: 3vw;
    }

    #container p {
        font-size: 2.3vw;
        line-height: 3vw;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/sankey.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/organization.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <p class="highcharts-description">
        Organization charts are a common case of hierarchical network charts,
        where the parent/child relationships between nodes are visualized.
        Highcharts includes a dedicated organization chart type that streamlines
        the process of creating these types of visualizations.
    </p>
</figure>
```

Comment: You can just use html in formatting the `name` of a node, e.g., `{id: 'Board', name: '<a href="https://highcharts.com" target="_blank">Board</a>'}` See the example of overriding the `nodeFormatter` from [docs](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/organization-chart#data-labels) for a better control of the resulting output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add href attribute to the title/name, but then only the text will be clickable. If you want to make clickable the whole node, use click event.

```
nodes: [
        {
      id: 'C',
      key: 'Cinnamon',
      events: {
        click() {
          location.href = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' +
            this.options.key;
        }
      }
    },
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lgq37pjv/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.organization.point.events.click